# HTTP Post to Onedrive RestAPI

Tags: onedrive

I'm trying to use C# for connecting to Onedrive Rest API platform, The URL that I need to connect is:

"asdfasdfLJLKJLKJK"

and the code I'm trying to run is as below:

```
using System.Net.Http;     

using (var client = new HttpClient())           
{                              
var content_new = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]{                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("access_token", "asdKJHKJH")});

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);   
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var response_web = await client.PostAsync("/drive", content_new);            
var responseString = await response_web.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
Console.WriteLine(responseString); 
Console.ReadLine();}
```

But for some odd reason it fails, also would like to know if I can read the data that PostAsync sends to the server? I mean the request URL as that might help troubleshooting too.

Comment: the address I'm calling is actually: 'https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive?access_code="asdf"'

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your request you are performing a POST operation on a drive, the OneDrive API does not support that action on the drive node.

If you are looking to create a new folder or upload a file, you'll want to perform that operation on https://api.onedrive.com/drive/root or where ever you'd like the operation to happen in the user's account.

To look up all of the supported actions and example requests see the OneDrive API [resource model](https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm#resource-model).